# Share the public link of a contract from a community

Tags: community, document

Hello, I develop a community and I need to display a button when the customer click on it, he download the file which is a PDF file stored like a file in a contract record.

I read the documentation and  know I have to query records in the ContentDocumentLink object and the ContentDistribution object.

The documentation says: "For organizations with Communities enabled, a document can only be shared with users and groups that are a part of the community the file was created in."
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

Unfortunately, the community profile can't query the ContentDocumentLink because the SOQL query return nothing.

The file has been stored from Salesforce and not from the community.

Do you have an idea to help me please?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Unless the record and the file has been shared with the Community Users, Community Users won't be able download it. You have to make sure that you share the record/file with appropriate users.

Comment: Yes, the file is shared with community users.

But, how can I get the sharing link to display in the community?

Comment: Have you checked this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_sharing_via_link.htm&type=5) and assigned the required permissions?

Comment: Yes, I check that link and I can get the public link of a file when I click on the link "Public Link" if the file was uploaded via chatter and made with "With All Access".

So it works for me, thank you.